# Upsert Not Working Correctly When Using a Random UUID for a field

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I am having an issue where if I use a string representing a random UUID as one of the fields in my case class, the upsert function in MongoDB does not work properly in that it fails to do the insert of the record.

For example, I have a simple case class such as

```
case class Foo(id : String, date : String)
```

I instantiate a value for this class as follows

```
val value = Foo(java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString, "2019-10-11")
```

I then insert this into a mongo collection as follows:

```
collection.findAndUpdate(BSONDocument("id" -> value.id), value, upsert = true).map(_.result[Foo])
```

The collection is empty intially and so the logic should be that it should insert `value` into the collection as it is not there. But it doesn't.

If I change how the `id` field value is generated, say as follows:

```
val value = Foo("123-ABC", "2019-10-11")
```

then it works and I get the record insert into the collection.

Typical values of randomUUID look like 80eedffc-3e49-488b-8274-5711ad984a0c. Is this not acceptable to mongo or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: First try to reproduce the same in the MongoShell

Comment: It's actually inserting the rows in the collection. But the findAndUpdate query is return a None instead of the actual row inserted. How can I get the actual row that is inserted.

Comment: If you have a look at the documentation, you can see the `fetchNewObject` option

Comment: Yes that was it.